# JS issue - accordion only working on first row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, accordion

I've added a code snippet for a table plugin in my WP site that is supposed to add an accordion under each product row in a table which will display more information when clicked.

The first accordion is working as it should, however all other accordions under each product row do not respond when clicked.

Any ideas for a fix?

Thanks

```
add_filter('wcpt_row', function($row_markup) {
  ob_start();
  ?>
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}   
</style>

<script>
var i;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {  
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "table-row") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "table-row";
    }
  });
}
</script>

<tr class="accordion">
<td colspan="100">Find out more about
     <?php global $product;
            echo $product->get_short_description();
      ?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="panel">
<td colspan="100">    
      <?php global $product;
            echo $product->get_description();
      ?>

</td>
</tr>

    <?
  return $row_markup . ob_get_clean();
} );
```

Comment: So this filter runs for each individual row? Then the style and script element should not be in there to begin with, there is no sense in repeating them for each and every single row, when they contain absolutely the same for each row in any case. Plus, by repeating the JS, you are adding _multiple_ event handlers to elements, and that is not what you want.

Comment: The `<script>` section has to be placed _once_ and _after_ the table

Comment: @Cbroe Thanks for your response. Apologies if this is basic knowledge however I'm very much a beginner with this. Is there any way you could explain what you mean in a little more detail? - If the style and script element should be elsewhere, do I add them to a separate code snippet or elsewhere? And if so how do would I link it to the same table? Is there any way you could show me how it should be displayed? Thanks in advance.